# Trying to add the currency symbol to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, currency, symbols, mysql-workbench

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT mshipType_Name,
       COUNT('x') AS mshipssold,
       sum(memberToMship_InductionFee+memberToMship_JoinFee+
           (IF(mshipOption_Period='year',
             TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR ,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),
             TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate)) * memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod)) as value
FROM membertomships
  INNER JOIN mshipoptions on membertomships.mshipOption_Id = mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id
  INNER JOIN mshiptypes on mshipoptions.mshipType_Id = mshiptypes.mshipType_Id
WHERE memberToMship_StartDate BETWEEN '2011-06-26' AND '2011-07-26'
GROUP BY mshipType_Name;
```

It will show the results like this:

```
            mshiptype_name       mshipsold       value
            --------------       ---------       -----
            gold                 3               3800.00
            silver               4               4800.00
```

Its fine can I get the results like this with pound symbol has added in value:

```
            mshiptype_name       mshipsold       value
            --------------       ---------       -----
            gold                 3               £ 3800.00
            silver               4               £ 4800.00
```

Is it possible with a MySQL query?

MODIFIED QUERY :

```
         SELECT  set names utf-8,mshipType_Name, COUNT('x') AS mshipssold,
                               CONCAT('£', sum(memberToMship_InductionFee+memberToMship_JoinFee+
                                  (IF(mshipOption_Period='year',
                                  TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR ,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),
                                  TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate)) * memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod))) as value
                              FROM membertomships
                              inner join mshipoptions on membertomships.mshipOption_Id = mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id
                              inner join mshiptypes on mshipoptions.mshipType_Id = mshiptypes.mshipType_Id
                              WHERE memberToMship_StartDate BETWEEN '2011-06-26' AND '2011-07-26'
                              GROUP BY mshipType_Name;





  Error Code: 1064
       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your       MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set names utf-8,mshipType_Name, COUNT('x') AS mshipssold,
                  ' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try with:

```
set names utf8;
SELECT mshipType_Name, COUNT('x') AS mshipssold,
                                sum(memberToMship_InductionFee+memberToMship_JoinFee+
                                  (IF(mshipOption_Period='year',
                                  TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR ,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),
                                  CONCAT('£ ', TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate)) * memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod)) ) as value
                              FROM membertomships
                              inner join mshipoptions on membertomships.mshipOption_Id = mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id
                              inner join mshiptypes on mshipoptions.mshipType_Id = mshiptypes.mshipType_Id
                              WHERE memberToMship_StartDate BETWEEN '2011-06-26' AND '2011-07-26'
                              GROUP BY mshipType_Name;
```

Comment: can you please tell us how can we write '£ ' or other symbol, like INR which is currently introduced, in database programing editor..??

because as of now I am unable to get how to write this.. :(

Comment: @Tudor Constantin : I know you would know about this so please descibe this

Comment: what is your db programming editor? it has to be able to use utf8 encodings - try to look at that

Comment: try put this `set names utf8;` before the query